# Is there a way to hide the "Share" button from all the sharepoint online pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, page-layout, share

Is there a way to hide the Share button from all the SharePoint online pages:-

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For modern UI, anyway you can use a modern script editor to do the same thing. However once you switch to another page, the button still will returns. If you want to restrict users from sharing, it may be better to change the sharing settings to make only owners can share.

[image]

Then other members will not have this button on the right top.

[image]

Comment: Manipulating the DOM via a modern script editor web part would be an unsupported customisation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages#supported-customizations-for-modern-pages

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add a Script Editor or a Content Editor webpart and add the following script (QCB1_Button4 should be the id of the button, but this may change, check with F12 in browser):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideEdit() {
        var edit = document.getElementById("QCB1_Button4");
        edit.style.display = "none";
    }       
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideEdit");
</script>
```

Please mark the answer if it works for you!

Comment: Script Editor or a Content Editor webpart are not available inside Modern Ui